# Ruby geocoding library compatible with latest Google maps, Yahoo maps, Bing APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

What Ruby / Rails geocoding library is compatible with (can fetch data from):

- latest Yahoo [PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) api
- latest Google [V3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [Bing maps API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx)

Please also comment on the compatibility with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby Geocoder supports Google V3 (the default), and can be configured to use Yahoo Placefinder or Bing. It's also Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9 compatible. It appears to have broader support and be more regularly maintained than geokit.

http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Answer (score -2):

http://geokit.rubyforge.org/

Comment from site about compability:

> Geokit is Ruby 1.9.1 compatible!

I don't know about geokit-rails and rails 3, but you need only geokit gem for geocoding.

Comment: Yap, but geokit doesn't have neither Yahoo PlaceFinder nor Bing maps integration.

Comment: It has Yahoo geocoder http://geokit.rubyforge.org/api/geokit-gem/Geokit/Geocoders/YahooGeocoder.html

Comment: And there is also geokit-gem fork with bing support http://github.com/tigrish/geokit-gem

Comment: Yahoo PlaceFinder is not the same as Yahoo Geocoder. Yahoo Geocoder is legacy.